# Amplify.config not configuring app for all components to access Userpool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services

Im working with Amplify in a react web app and im having trouble trying to use Amplify functions outside the directory where `Amplify.configure` is called. This is with specific reference to Amplify's `Auth.signUp` and Auth functions.

When i call `Amplify.configure`(awsconfig) in my main (root) `index.js` file, it doesn't allow me to globally use the `Auth.signUp` function outside of such file, returning an error => *No Userpool*

However, if i were to call `Auth.signUp` in the `index.js` file under `Amplify.configure`(awsconfig), my cognito userpool is found and i am able to add users.

If for example i go and try to call `Auth.signUp` in another component where `Amplify.configure` isn't stated, the error is produced.

I have changed the order of all the imports ensuring the component that contains `Auth.signUp` is last. However, this error still persists.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out?